# How to convert UNISTR('K%') in oracle to bigquery

Tags: sql, oracle, google-bigquery

Iam converting the oracle query in big query

In the query there is UNISTR('K%') , i dont know how to convert this in bigquery

can someone please help me how to convert UNISTR('K%') to bigquery standard sql?

Comment: You probably don't need it at all.  Just try `'K%'`.

Comment: I have tried it. It doesnt show error and i believe both oracle and bq results are same